# Como obtener la media de tres vector3

Tags: c#, unity, vectores

Estoy intentando obtener el promedio de tres Vector3 utilizando el código adjunto, pero obtengo un error al compilar que dice;

*"Operator '+=' cannot be applied to operands of type 'Vector3' and 'method group'"*

Este error se refiere a la ultima linea del código y no se como resolverlo. ¿Qué es un "method group"?

Para poneros en contexto, la intención de este código es la de reposicionar la cámara en una experiencia de Oculus sobre la cual estoy trabajando.

No tengo mucha experiencia programando ya que estoy empezando. He logrado llegar hasta aquí al intentar comprender y mezclar varias soluciones aportadas por la comunidad. Estaría muy agradecido si alguien puede ayudarme a resolver este paso.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
    
public class Calibration : MonoBehaviour
{
  Vector3 averagePos = new Vector3(0f, 0f, 0f);
            
  Vector3[] positionArray = new[] { 
            new Vector3(0f, 0f, 0f), 
            new Vector3(0f, 0f, 0f),
            new Vector3(0f, 0f, 0f),
  };
}

 void Update()
 {

 Vector3 averagePos (Vector3[] positionArray)
                    {
                     float x = 0f;
                     float y = 0f;
                     float z = 0f;

                     foreach (Vector3 pos in positionArray)
                     {
                      x += pos.x;
                      y += pos.y;
                      z += pos.z;
                      }
                      return new Vector3 (x / positionArray.Length, y / positionArray.Length, z / positionArray.Length);                                            
                      }
                        
                     this.transform.position += averagePos;
    }
```

Comment: You are at [es.so]. Please translate your question or it will be closed. Bienvenido a [es.so]. Por favor traduce tu pregunta al castellano o terminará cerrada. Saludos

Comment: No olvides traducir el título de la pregunta también.

Answer (score 0):

El problema parece ser —en terminos simples— que estás sumando un *Vector3* con un delegado y no con otro *Vector3*.

Probablemente el error es que el compilador interpreta que estás sumando al objeto *this.transform.position* más la función *averagePos* (más específicamente su dirección de memoria) en vez de sumarlo más el atributo *averagePos* de la clase *Calibration* —que creo yo es lo que intentas hacer—.

Esto último sucede porque el atributo *averagePos* de la clase *Calibration* y la función *Update* están declarados en distintos scopes, es decir el atributo lo declaraste dentro de la clase mientras que la función la declaraste afuera; ambos deben ir adentro de la clase.

Por otro lado la función *averagePos*, también debe ir dentro de la clase *Calibration*, pero debes cambiarle el nombre ya que hay un atributo que se llama igual. Por ejemplo el atributo podría llamarse *averagePos* y la función/método, *averagePosition*.

Una última observación que hice en tu código, es que debes inicializar al atributo *averagePos* de la clase *Calibration*, antes de usarlo en la función *Update*, ya que de lo contrario tu código no va a funcionar —eso pienso yo—.

[Creando y Usando Scripts - Unity3D](https://docs.unity3d.com/es/530/Manual/CreatingAndUsingScripts.html#:%7E:text=Creando%20Scripts&text=Usted%20puede%20crear%20un%20nuevo,en%20el%20Panel%20del%20Proyecto.)